# Struggling in SAS. I could use assistance

Tags: sas

I am really new to SAS and I am struggling. I am trying to create a logistic regression model. The three variables I need are student, balance, and income. but I keep on getting an error message. The error I am getting:

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 72         
 NOTE: PROCEDURE LOGISTIC used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.00 seconds
       
 ERROR: File WORK.CREDIT.DATA does not exist.
 NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
 73         proc logistic data=credit;
 74            class gender/ param=glm;
 75            model default (event='1') = gender age;
 76         run;
 77         
 78         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 90
```

Code:

```
proc logistic data=credit;
   class gender/ param=glm;
   model default (event='1') = gender age;
run;
```

I changed my code to:

```
proc logistic WORK.IMPORT;
 class gender/ param=glm; model default (event='1') = student balance income; 
 run;
```

and now I am getting this:

```
      OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 72         
 NOTE: PROCEDURE LOGISTIC used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.00 seconds
       
 NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
 73         proc logistic WORK.IMPORT;
                          ___________
                          22
                          201
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, ALPHA, COVOUT, DATA, DESC, DESCENDING, EXACTONLY, EXACTOPTIONS, IN, 
               INEST, INMODEL, MAXRESPONSELEVELS, MISSING, MULTIPASS, NAMELEN, NOFIT, NOPRINT, ORDER, OUT, OUTDESIGN, OUTDESIGNONLY, 
               OUTEST, OUTMODEL, PLOT, PLOTS, REF, REFERENCE, ROCOPTIONS, RORDER, SIMPLE, TRUNCATE.  
 ERROR 201-322: The option is not recognized and will be ignored.
 74          class gender/ param=glm; model default (event='1') = student balance income;
 75          run;
 76         
 77         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 89
```

I am getting closer:

```
proc logistic data= WORK.IMPORT;
 class gender/ param=glm; model default (event='1') = student balance income; 
 run;
```

New error variable gender not found.

Comment: You cannot use the WORK dataset CREDIT before you have created it.

Comment: I have a dataset in excel called default. But in SAS it is name WORK.IMPORT.

Comment: I have this now: proc logistic WORK.IMPORT;
class gender/ param=glm;
   model default (event='1') = student balance income;
run; now the error I am getting is: Syntax error and The option is not recognized and will be ignored.

Comment: You need to show the SAS log for the new error message in the question like you did for the previous error.  That way we can see exactly what part of the syntax SAS is seeing as an error.

Comment: Hey Tom, I have updated the post with my changes.

Comment: Your removed the DATA= keyword so SAS doesn't understand that the string `work.import` should be interpreted as the name of the dataset to use.  From where you have placed it SAS is expecting some option part of the PROC LOGISTIC statement, but there is no option named `work.import`.

Comment: Hey Tom, looks like I am close. Now I am getting Variable GENDER not found. I was able to update my code.

Comment: Check that `gender` is a variable in your imported data. If it isn't, remove it from your `class` statement. The `class` statement defines categorical variables in your model. SAS automatically converts them to binary 1/0 indicators. You need to declare all categorical or binary variables with `class` in order to use them properly.

Comment: It is not. I have three variables: default student balance income

Comment: Then remove `gender` from your class statement and add any nominal variables to the class statement instead so that proc logistic knows to convert them to binary indicators.

Comment: Let me try it now

Comment: I tried this: proc logistic data= WORK.IMPORT;
 class student/ param=glm; model default (event='1') = student; 
 class balance/ param=glm; model default (event='1') = balance;
 class income/ param=glm; model default (event='1')= income;

 run;
Is this correct?

Comment: ERROR: The CLASS statement must precede the MODEL statement.

Comment: Your errors are telling you exactly what the problem is. Your first error told you that you had a syntax error. Your second error told you a variable in your model does not exist in the dataset. Your third error tells you that the class statement precedes the model statement. You need read these and diagnose the cause. Error messages are all hints as to what the issue is. If the class statement must precede the model statement, where do you think the class statement should go? Experiment with it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the basics and use `sashelp.heart` to create a simple logistic regression model and break down each statement.

```
proc logistic data=sashelp.heart plots=all;
    class sex(ref='Male') / param=glm;

    model status(event='Dead') = Sex Weight Height AgeAtStart Smoking;
run;
```

1. `proc logistic data=sashelp.heart plots=all;`

Start the `proc logistic` procedure, which creates logistic regression models, and print all the plots it produces. Read our data from `sashelp.heart`.

2. `class sex(ref='Male') / param=glm;`

Tell `proc logistic` that the variable `sex` is a categorical variable. We want to make our reference value males and use GLM encoding. The `/` indicates additional options for the `class` statement. Many procedures use this type of options syntax. [Check the procedure's documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_syntax05.htm&locale=en&showBanner=walkup) to learn about its options and features.

The `class` statement must precede the `model` statement. `proc logistic` needs to know which variables are categorical before it starts modeling.

3. `model status(event='Dead') = Sex Weight Height AgeAtStart Smoking;`

Estimate a logistic regression model using `dead` as our event of interest. In other words, we're creating parameter estimates of the log odds that someone will die.

Comment: I am so sorry. I need three different variables. They are student, balance, and income.

Comment: Please study the sample code provided, adapt it to your process, and review the documentation. You need to understand how `proc logistic` works so that you can adapt it to your code and write new code in the future. The code I provided you is easily adaptable to your current problem. All of the answers are provided for you here and in the documentation.  I cannot write your code for you without data, anyway. For targeted analytics questions, you should post in either cross-validated or the SAS community forums.